# What Property ID should be used instead of "WixShellExecTarget" in case of several CustomActions with BinaryKey/DllEntry?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I use following configuration to start my server after installation of application:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='LaunchApplication' After='InstallFinalize'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#startServer.vbs]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA"  
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Execute="immediate"
    Impersonate="yes" />
```

Installer executes script startServer.vbs at the end of installation procedure.
What property Id should I use if I need to execute several custom actions?
For example if I will use following configuration. What property Id should I use for StopApplication custom action?

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='LaunchApplication' After='InstallFinalize'/>
  <Custom Action='StopApplication' Before='InstallValidate'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#startServer.vbs]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA"  
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Execute="immediate"
    Impersonate="yes" />

<Property Id="???" Value="[#stopServer.vbs]" />
<CustomAction Id="StopApplication" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA"  
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Execute="immediate"
    Impersonate="yes" />
```

**UPDATE:**
There is error "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run." during installation  if I use following configuration:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action='StartServerCustomAction' After='InstallFinalize'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<Binary Id='StartServerScript' SourceFile='startServer.vbs' />
<CustomAction Id='StartServerCustomAction' BinaryKey='StartServerScript' JScriptCall='startServerSub' Return='check' />
```

**startServer.vbs**

```
Public Function startServerSub()
   Return 0
End Function
```

Comment: You can run vbscript custom actions directly - there's no need to run them from something else. This should help: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-use-CustomAction-with-a-VBScript-td700420.html

Comment: @PhilDW Please see updated question. It does not work. Installer could not find script by some reason. But script is present in directory.

Comment: You've got an immediate custom action that runs before any files are installed so it's not going to be there, that's the main implementation issue. Adapt the example at that link where the script is stored in the Binary table to get past that issue.